# Gold paint this year used in the NFL

Tags: nfl

Does anyone know for sure (and could possibly give a source) as to why the NFL this year is using gold paint for the 50-yard markers?

I assume this is somehow related to an anniversary, since it is the 50th Superbowl, but I haven't been able to verify it, and I hadn't actually heard any commentator say it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Super Bowl 50 is exactly the reason for it.  Here's a source that also mentions some of the other things (much gold-related) that the NFL is doing to commemorate the milestone:
http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/eye-on-football/25120528/nfl-going-gold-in-2015-to-celebrate-super-bowl-50-5-things-to-know

There was even a mini-controversy recently about the Oakland Raiders not painting their 50 yard line gold:
http://www.sbnation.com/2015/9/22/9377843/raiders-50-yard-line-gold-rebellion-49ers

Comment: Very nice answer.  I did notice this weekend, actually, that the branding in the broadcast had the SB trophy with a gold 50 in the background.